# How to do a three way call in PlumVoice?

Tags: ivr, vxml

Is there any possibility of do a three way call to listen in realtime the outgoing call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With PlumVoice that is a standard VoiceXML browser I don't know, but Voximal can manage a conference room from the VoiceXML. It is based on Asterisk PBX and have high level features to manage calls...